# Parse XML with duplicate elementnames in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse the following XML structure in C#. I want to create an List> with the currencies.

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"   xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
<gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
  <Cube time="2013-09-27">
    <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3537"/>
    <Cube currency="JPY" rate="133.28"/>
    <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
    <Cube currency="CZK" rate="25.690"/>
    <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4573"/>
    (....)
```

I've tried using XDocument.Descendants, but it's not returning anything. I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that the Cube-element is  used in several levels.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var currencies = from cube in xdoc.Descendants("Cube")
                    select new
                        {
                            Currency = cube.Attribute("currency").Value,
                            Rate = cube.Attribute("rate").Value
                        };

foreach (var currency in currencies)
    this.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(currency.Currency, Convert.ToDouble(currency.Rate)));
```

How can I parse the XML structure to get the currencies?

Comment: had the same problem with exactly the same file from ECB :) Thanks a lot to @L.B - works fine

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems with your code

- Every `Cube` doesn't have `currency` and `rate` attribute
- You ignore the Xml namespace

Since it seems you want to create a **dictionary**  according to your code:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fname);

var dict = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Cube")
               .Where(cube => cube.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name == "currency"))
               .ToDictionary(cube => cube.Attribute("currency").Value,
                             cube => (decimal)cube.Attribute("rate"));
```

PS: You don't have to parse the `rate` explicitly. It can be done while reading the xml by *casting*

Answer (score 1):

Try xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//Cube/Cube/Cube[@name='currency']")

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a namespace (the Cube elements are not in the default empty namespace) and you have to check if the Cube element has indeed the currency attribute.

This is the closest solution to your curent code that will work:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace nsSys = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";

var currencies = from cube in xdoc.Descendants(nsSys+ "Cube")
                 where cube.Attribute("currency") !=null
                 select new
                 {
                      Currency = cube.Attribute("currency").Value,
                      Rate = cube.Attribute("rate").Value
                 };
```

[Used this Answer as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998837/578411)