# XML Parsing from the string?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using In App Purchase in my app. Here's the Receipt I had after the successful purchase:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Receipt Version="1.0" CertificateId="xxxyyy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt">
        <ProductReceipt PurchasePrice="$9.99" PurchaseDate="2014-11-18T08:04:37.572Z" ExpirationDate="9999-12-31T00:00:00Z" ProductId="product_id" ProductType="Consumable" AppId="xxx-yyy" Id="xxx-yyy" PublisherDeviceId="xxx-yyy"  PublisherUserId="" MicrosoftProductId="xxx-yyy" MicrosoftAppId="xxx-yyy"  />
    </Receipt>
```

//stored as the string 'receipt'

I need to display it to the user, But I'm getting error. Here's my code:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(receipt).Root.Element("ProductReceipt"); //receipt id the string
string Price = xDoc.Attribute("PurchasePrice").Value;
```

'xDoc' is always null. Since it's null, I got an exception on getting price.

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Please help me how to get the 'PurchasePrice' from that xml string!

Comment: you're missing a namespace

Comment: @rene What is that? Please tell me

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2998837/578411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt";
var xDoc = XDocument
               .Parse(receipt)
               .Root
               .Element(ns + "ProductReceipt"); //Use namespace ProductReceipt is in
```

Remember that if your xml contains `xmlns` markup that node and it's children are part of that namespace. This is to prevent name clashes of elements.

The Wikipedia article is a good starting point if you want to learn more about that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace