# Linq to XML Read XPath (Read all nodes)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

This is my XML file, contains a xmlns. I'm trying to read all the nodes of the file dynamic.

The first node (Document) works fine, but the others node no.

Could help me with this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document>
<BkToCstmrAcctRpt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:325235:tech:xsd:camt.052.001.03">
<GrpHdr>
<MsgId>NONREF</MsgId>
<CreDtTm>2017-09-27T15:10:01.597560</CreDtTm>
<MsgPgntn>
<PgNb>1</PgNb>
<LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd>
</MsgPgntn>
</GrpHdr>
<Rpt>
<Id>T2S</Id>
<CreDtTm>2017-09-27T15:10:01.597560+02:00</CreDtTm>
<Acct>
<Id>
<Othr>
<Id>24234234234234234234we234</Id>
</Othr>
</Id>
<Ccy>EUR</Ccy>
<Ownr>
<Id>
<OrgId>
</OrgId>
</Id>
</Ownr>
<Svcr>
<FinInstnId>
<BICFI>HJASDESPBESMMXXX</BICFI>
</FinInstnId>
</Svcr>
</Acct>
<Bal>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Prtry>CASH</Prtry>
</CdOrPrtry>
</Tp>
<Amt Ccy="EUR">0.00</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<Dt>
<Dt>2017-09-27</Dt>
</Dt>
</Bal>
<Bal>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Prtry>PCAS</Prtry>
</CdOrPrtry>
</Tp>
<Amt Ccy="EUR">469035826.79</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<Dt>
<Dt>2017-09-27</Dt>
</Dt>
</Bal>
<Bal>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Prtry>AOIC</Prtry>
</CdOrPrtry>
</Tp>
<Amt Ccy="EUR">0.00</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<Dt>
<Dt>2017-09-27</Dt>
</Dt>
</Bal>
<Bal>
<Tp>
<CdOrPrtry>
<Prtry>SPCA</Prtry>
</CdOrPrtry>
</Tp>
<Amt Ccy="EUR">469035826.79</Amt>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<Dt>
<Dt>2017-09-27</Dt>
</Dt>
</Bal>
<TxsSummry>
<TtlNtriesPerBkTxCd>
<NbOfNtries>0</NbOfNtries>
<Sum>0.00</Sum>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<BkTxCd>
<Prtry>
<Cd>AVLI</Cd>
</Prtry>
</BkTxCd>
</TtlNtriesPerBkTxCd>
<TtlNtriesPerBkTxCd>
<NbOfNtries>313</NbOfNtries>
<Sum>469035826.79</Sum>
<CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
<BkTxCd>
<Prtry>
<Cd>AVSI</Cd>
</Prtry>
</BkTxCd>
</TtlNtriesPerBkTxCd>
</TxsSummry>
</Rpt>
</BkToCstmrAcctRpt>
</Document>
```

And this is my source code:

```
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(_ms))
    {
        var docXml = XDocument.Load(reader);

        var prefix = ((XElement)(docXml.Root.FirstNode)).Name.LocalName;
        var nameSpace = ((XElement)(docXml.Root.FirstNode)).Name.NamespaceName;

        XmlNameTable nameTable = reader.NameTable;
        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace(string.Empty, nameSpace);

        var filterOpt = docXml.Root.Document.XPathSelectElements("BkToCstmrAcctRpt", namespaceManager);
    }
```

If i read the xpath //Document works ok, but if i tried to read //Document/BkToCstmrAcctRpt or another sub-node the result is count = 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XDocument containing namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998710/xdocument-containing-namespaces)

Comment: It's not a duplicated question. The XML is different, it's no a node header namespace.

Comment: the solution is the same ...

Comment: Hi Rene, thanks for your reply. I tried with the solution of the other post and don't work for me. Do you have any idea to resolve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following which fixes namespace issue. :

```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement BkToCstmrAcctRpt = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "BkToCstmrAcctRpt").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = BkToCstmrAcctRpt.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement LastPgInd = BkToCstmrAcctRpt.Descendants(ns + "LastPgInd").FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdweng