# Read the values from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using `XDocument` in order to load XML file, with this content, i am trying to read `<pjob:job_variables>` nodes content, and for each node in `<pjob:job_variables>` to get the name and the value,
so for `<pjob:var name="XMLFilePath">E:\PP\REPC.xt</pjob:var>` to get the name `XMLFilePath` and the value of it `E:\PP\REPC.xt`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?P_command version="1.0"?>
<pjob:job_command xmlns:pjob="http://www.pp.com/schemas" name="SubmitJob">
    <pjob:job_variables>
        <pjob:var name="XMLFilePath">E:\PP\REPC.xt</pjob:var>
        <pjob:var name="TSLFilePath">E:\PP\REPC.tl</pjob:var>
        <pjob:var name="_sys_BitmapType">jpeg</pjob:var>
        .........
    </pjob:job_variables>
    <pjob:doc_variables>  
        <pjob:var name="CompanyPhone"/>
        <pjob:var name="CompanyWebsite">www.site.com</pjob:var>    
        .........
    </pjob:doc_variables>
</pjob:job_command>
```

i tried a lot of variations, like

```
string name, value = String.Empty;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../assets/packet.xml");
var authors = doc.Descendants("job_variables");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
  name = node.name;
  value = node.value;
}
```

but he doesn't find the `Descendants`, how can i acheive it?

Comment: When your xml has namespaces [you need to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998710/xdocument-containing-namespaces)

Comment: try using DescendantNodes instead of Descendants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to prepend the namespace `pjob`:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.pp.com/schemas";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../assets/packet.xml");
var authors = doc.Root.Element(ns + "job_variables").Elements();
```

Or use the `XName.Get()` method:

```
var authors = doc.Root.Element(XName.Get("job_variables", "http://www.pp.com/schemas")).Elements();
```

This gets all children of the "job_variables" element.

As specified in the comments, to get the elements of both `job_variables` and `doc_variables`, you don't even need to access the elements via their names; just use `doc.Root.Elements().Elements()`.

Answer (score 0):

try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement job_command = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "job_command").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace pjobNs = job_command.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("pjob");

            var results = job_command.Descendants(pjobNs +  "var").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                value = (string)x
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```