# XDocument not finding specific element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a custom function that gets an element by name.

```
public static XElement GetElement(this XElement element, string elementName)
{
    if (!element.HasElements)
        throw new HasNoElementsException("");

    return element.Element(element.GetDefaultNamespace() + elementName) ?? 
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("");
}
```

The function works normally, but I have a problem with one specific xml file exemplified here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<elementA xmlns="http://www.link1.com.br">
    <elementB>
        ...other elements
    </elementB>
    <elementC xmlns="http://www.link2.com.br" schemaLocation="http://www.link1.com.br file.xsd">
        <elementD>
            ...other elements
        </elementD>
    </elementC>
</elementA>
```

When I try to get the elementB in the xml, it works, but when I try to get the elementC the `ElementNotFoundException` is thrown.

Sorry for my bad English, brazilian here! :)

Comment: Because `elementC` has a namespace. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783747/8951109 for reference...

Comment: Yeah, but I need to specify the namespace, in other words I need to know the namespace value. Have some way to make it dynamic, using the  XDocument.Element function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static XElement GetElement(this XElement element, string elementName)
{
    if (!element.HasElements)
        throw new HasNoElementsException("");

    return element.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName.Equals(elementName)) ??
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("");
}
```

This would be a solution which gets the first element with the specified name without needing its default namespace.